# Java Interface error - incompatible types

Tags: java, generics, interface, compiler-errors

I have a problem with an interface in Java.

The interface:

```
public interface Comparable<ContentType> {
public boolean isGreater ( ContentType pContent );
public boolean isEqual ( ContentType pContent );
public boolean isLess ( ContentType pContent );
}
```

The class "Point" implementing the interface:

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point>{

private double x;
private double y;

public Point ( double pX, double pY ) {
    x = pX;
    y = pY;
}

public boolean isLess ( Point pContent ) {
    if ( this.distance() < pContent.distance()  ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isEqual ( Point pContent ) {
    if ( this.distance() == pContent.distance()  ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isGreater ( Point pContent ) {
    if ( this.distance() > pContent.distance()  ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public double distance() {
    return Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y );
}

}
```

The class "Algorithms" has an insort-method for the interface Comparable and tests this insort-method:

```
public class Algorithms {

public static List<Comparable> insortComparable( Queue<Comparable> pQueue ) {
    List<Comparable> l = new List<Comparable>();
    while ( !pQueue.isEmpty() ) {
        if ( l.isEmpty() ) {
            l.append(pQueue.front());
            pQueue.dequeue();
        } else {
            l.toFirst();
            while (l.hasAccess() && pQueue.front().isGreater(l.getContent())) {
                l.next();
            }
            if ( l.hasAccess() ) {
                l.insert(pQueue.front());
            } else {
                l.append(pQueue.front());
            }
            pQueue.dequeue();
        }
    }
    return l;
}

public static Queue<Point> randomQueuePoint() {
    Queue<Point> q = new Queue<Point>();    
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        q.enqueue( new Point( Math.random()*100, Math.random()) );
    }
    return q;
}

public void test() {
    Queue<Point> q = randomQueuePoint();
    List<Point> l = insortComparable(q);
}

}
```

In the test method I call the method `insortComparable(q)` but the compiler underlines q and the compiler says:

> incompatible types: Queue<Point> cannot be converted to Queue<Comparable>

Where is the problem?

---

Update:

I found my mistake and I wanted to give you an update, so people who have the same problem get some help.

One could say:

```
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> insortComparable( Queue<T> pQueue ) {
    List<T> l = new List<T>();
    while ( !pQueue.isEmpty() ) {
        if ( l.isEmpty() ) {
            l.append(pQueue.front());
            pQueue.dequeue();
        } else {
            l.toFirst();
            while (l.hasAccess() && pQueue.front().isGreater(l.getContent())) {
                l.next();
            }
            if ( l.hasAccess() ) {
                l.insert(pQueue.front());
            } else {
                l.append(pQueue.front());
            }
            pQueue.dequeue();
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: While `Point` "is-a" `Comparable`, `Queue<Point>` is not a `Queue<Comparable>`. You would need to add covariance keywords to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

A `Queue<Point>` indeed isn't a `Queue<Comparable>`.
The simplest way to conceptualize this is that you could add `SomeOtherComaparbale` instance to a `Queue<Comparable>` but not to a `Queue<Point>`.

Conceptually, you don't want a "Queue of Comparable", but a "Queue of any type that implements Comparable". In Java syntax, that would be:

```
public static List<Comparable> insortComparable(Queue<? extends Comparable> pQueue) {
    // Here ------------------------------------------^
```